# Where are exceptions logged on Phalcon Framework?

Tags: php, phalcon

I have an existing application based on Phalcon Framework, my problem is that Exceptions is not been logged anywhere.

When some fatal error occurs I can see it on php erros, but not the Exceptions.

Where default logs is writen? Can I define a custom path for the logs?

Thank you for help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Phalcon PHP Exception Logging

You handle exceptions in a `try...catch` loop:

```
try { ...run application here } catch ( \Exception $e ) { ...do logging here }
```

Instantiate the built in Phalcon logger ( note: I am using the File adapter ):

```
$logger = new \Phalcon\Logger\Adapter\File("../app/logs/exceptions.log");
```

Log the exception messages:

```
$logger->log($e->getMessage());
```

**Solution Summary**

```
$logger = new \Phalcon\Logger\Adapter\File("../app/logs/test.log");
try { ...run application here } catch ( \Exception $e ) { 
    $logger->log($e->getMessage());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the following exception handler in my code:

```
    // We register the events manager
    $di->set('dispatcher', function () {

        // Create an event manager
        $eventsManager = new EventsManager();

        // Attach a listener
        $eventsManager->attach("dispatch:beforeException", function ($event, $dispatcher, $exception) {
            // Alternative way, controller or action doesn't exist
            switch ($exception->getCode()) {
                case \Phalcon\Dispatcher::EXCEPTION_HANDLER_NOT_FOUND:
                    $strUrlRelocate = "http://" . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . "/";
                    header("Location:" . $strUrlRelocate);
                    break;

                case \Phalcon\Dispatcher::EXCEPTION_ACTION_NOT_FOUND:
                    error_log($exception);
                    break;
            }
        });

        $dispatcher = new MvcDispatcher();

        // Bind the eventsManager to the view component
        $dispatcher->setEventsManager($eventsManager);

        return $dispatcher;

    }, true);
```

Maybe an working example will help you.